# How to scp file to remote servers' root directory and run sudo commands?

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, scp

NOTE: The servers does not share the same password but I will setup no-password login at first.

Here's the use case, I need to do these below step by step in my `deploy.sh`:

1. scp files to remote servers' `/opt/bin` directory, which requires root permission
2. After that, ssh into remote servers and run `sudo install.sh`, which also requires root permission
3. Login as root is not allowed by servers

I noticed there's way[1] to `ssh` and run sudo command but it seems not work for `scp`.

It really bothered me a lot ...

[1]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310299/proper-way-to-sudo-over-ssh

BTW: I think one of the possible way is that scp files to a normal directory and then ssh and run `sudo mv * /opt/bin; sudo install.sh`.

Comment: you can provide commands in /etc/sudoers with NOPASSWD. Then you can run sudo without prompting for password.

Answer (score 0):

Bring the mountain to the prophet?

```
ssh user@remote "sudo scp -r user@local:/path/to/files /opt/bin"
```

It seems like that is a whole lot of privilege with nary a password to be seen, which would make me nervous.

Comment: How the remote scp local without input local's password?

Comment: By generating a key on the remote system as root, and putting it in the local user/machines .ssh/authorized_keys